# What is the proper way to load this edge-list file format?

Tags: python, networkx

How can I load this graph, given this file format:

1 2 5 3
4 1 3 5 10
5 2

Where the first value is the source node, and the spaces are delimited by a tab-character.

I used **Networkx** to load the data, but this line of code renders `graph_data` empty:

```
graph_data = nx.read_edgelist(filename, delimiter='\t')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
graph_data = nx.read_adjlist(filename, delimiter='\t')
```

The documentation for read_adjlist is [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.adjlist.read_adjlist.html).

You're using a different command `read_edgelist` which assumes that each edge gets its own line.